# Windows API - Fetching results of FormatMessage() into a std::string

Tags: c++, winapi

I am new to the Windows API, and while I figured out how to get system message code descriptions, I would like to know if there **is a better, more elegant way to do so**.  Or, for educational purposes, **if there is any other way in general.**

```
DWORD WINAPI FormatMessage(
  _In_      DWORD dwFlags,
  _In_opt_  LPCVOID lpSource,
  _In_      DWORD dwMessageId,
  _In_      DWORD dwLanguageId,
  _Out_     LPTSTR lpBuffer,
  _In_      DWORD nSize,
  _In_opt_  va_list *Arguments
);
```

UPDATED CODE AFTER COMMENT:

```
std::string bmd2File::getErrorCodeDescription(long errorCode) const throw (bmd2Exception)
{
  #ifdef _WIN32

    char MessageFromSystem[1024];
    bool messageReceived = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
                  0,
                  errorCode,
                  1033,                          // US English
                  MessageFromSystem,
                  1024,
                  0);
    std::ostringstream ostr;

    if (!messageReceived)
      ostr << "Error code: " << errorCode;
    else
      ostr << "Error code " << errorCode << " with message: " << MessageFromSystem;

    return ostr.str();

  #else
  #endif
}
```

OLD CODE

```
std::string bmd2File::getErrorCodeDescription(long errorCode) const throw (bmd2Exception)
{
  #ifdef _WIN32

    char MessageFromSystem[1024];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
                  0,
                  errorCode,
                  1033,                          // US English
                  MessageFromSystem,
                  1024,
                  0);
    return std::string(MessageFromSystem);

  #else
  #endif
}
```

Do I look like a noob or is this code alright?

Comment: How about the char array [1024]?  Seems low-level to specify a char array in bytes and just cross your fingers to hope that it's big enough.

Comment: Rather than hard-coding the buffer size let the function allocate it for you. You can bitwise OR FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER to the first parameter for the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not alright.  From the [MSDN documentation of FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), we see:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.

That means that this function has a possibility of failing.  You should check the return value to see if it failed and somehow handle that, perhaps by returning a string with the error code from `GetLastError`.  If you don't handle it, you are probably passing uninitialized data to the `std::string` constructor and you could be causing undefined behavior.